# Наследник от QSqlTableModel не понимает NULL

Tags: python, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel

в PyQT5 собираю обычную стандартную связку `sqlite` + `QSqlTableModel` + `QTableView`. Всё работает, записи редактируются, изменения в бд сохраняются.
Далее, допустим, я хочу добавить выравнивание текста в ячейках через `Qt.TextAlignmentRole` (не важно), для этого я создаю свою модель, наследуюсь от `QSqlTableModel` и переопределяю метод `data`:

```
class MyTableModelSql(QSqlTableModel):
       
    def data(self, idx, role):
        return super().data(idx, role)

model = MyTableModelSql(self, db=db)
```

С этого момента редактировать строки в которых есть пустые NULL ячейки уже не получается, в вертикальном заголовке появляется знак `(!)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая ссылка гугла ведет на этот [вопрос](https://forum.qt.io/topic/90363/inexplicable-qsqlquerymodel-handling-of-null-value) на офф. форуме qt. Есть помеченный ответ. Автор ответа объясняет, что проблема связана возвращаемым `QVariant` своей модели, который отличается от возвращаемого от стандартной модели `QSqlTableModel`. Причина в особенности языка python, в котором нет типа *Null*, в С++ такой проблемы нет, и предлагает какой-то страшный костыль по обвязке(обертке?) результата. Костыль у меня не заработал.

Собственно 2 вопроса:

- тот ответ был дан в 2018 году, за 5 лет возможно проблема была решена стандартными средствами `PyQT`, если кто-то знает решение `прошу помочь`
- как мне установить выравнивание текста в ячейках без перенаследования класса `QSqlTableModel`, есть ли другие способы?

Прикладываю минимальный код, полностью воспроизводящий ошибку:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel, QSqlDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableView, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("main.db")
db.open()

# run once
# query0 = QSqlQuery("DROP TABLE testtable")
# query1 = QSqlQuery("CREATE TABLE testtable (col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT)")
# query2 = QSqlQuery("""INSERT INTO testtable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES 
#                   ('full row', 3453, 345),
#                   ('half row', NULL, 6343),
#                   ('empty row', NULL, NULL)""")

class MyTableModelSql(QSqlTableModel):
   
    def data(self, idx, role):
        return super().data(idx, role)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # model = QSqlTableModel редактирование записей работает
        # model = MyTableModelSql редактирование записей не работает
        model = MyTableModelSql(self, db=db)
        model.setTable('testtable')
        model.select()
        self.view = QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(model)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Код из форума работает с предоставленным вами кодом (Версия PyQt5 == 5.15.9 т.е. последняя Версия python 3.10.0) единственное, что пришлось написать `from PyQt5 import sip` вместо `import sip` как на форуме

Comment: да я так и делал, разумеется, from PyQt5 import sip, у меня вьюшка не заполняется, пустая, отправьте пожалуйста полный метод data

Comment: [Этот](https://pastebin.com/YY8aDs4R) код сработал. Возможно ничего не выводит т.к. во втором варианте кода на форуме написано `.value` тогда как `value` - это функция и нужно писать `.value()`

Comment: да, действительно, я невнимательный, напишите код как ответ, помечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код из форума не сработал т.к. `QVariant.value` - функция поэтому нужно использовать `QVariant.value()` а не `QVariant.value` Вот исправленный код:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import sip
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel, QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableView, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("main.db")
db.open()


# run once
# query0 = QSqlQuery("DROP TABLE testtable")
# query1 = QSqlQuery("CREATE TABLE testtable (col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT)")
# query2 = QSqlQuery("""INSERT INTO testtable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
#                   ('full row', 3453, 345),
#                   ('half row', NULL, 6343),
#                   ('empty row', NULL, NULL)""")

class MyTableModelSql(QSqlTableModel):

    def data(self, idx, role):
        was_enabled = sip.enableautoconversion(QVariant, False)
        value = super().data(idx, role)
        sip.enableautoconversion(QVariant, was_enabled)

        if not value.isValid():
            return None
        if value.isNull():
            return None

        return value.value()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # model = QSqlTableModel редактирование записей работает
        # model = MyTableModelSql редактирование записей не работает
        model = MyTableModelSql(self, db=db)
        model.setTable('testtable')
        model.select()
        self.view = QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(model)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю точно как Phyton (я на с++ пишу), но вы role проверяете? DisplayRole или там еще много разных вариантов вроде бы.

И меня один встречный вопрос мучает давно. Можно в питоне зайти отладчиком в функцию например в super().data(idx, role) ?

> Далее, допустим, я хочу добавить выравнивание текста в ячейках через Qt.TextAlignmentRole (не важно), для этого я создаю свою модель, наследуюсь от QSqlTableModel и переопределяю метод data:

Я конечно могу ошибаться, но роль TextAlignmentRole  вы должны реализовывать сами, создавать контейнер, где хранятся элайменты для колонок и т.д.

QSqlTableModel реализует только DisplayRole и EditRole. Во всяком случае так в Qt 4.

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите.